# TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor (What is the reason ?)

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I always use following command to create a contract instance without any problem :

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xe1623AAf57fCbe260F022404C730ae32aebe39F6');
```

However, when currently I use this command, I receive following error :

```
TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
```

**What is the reason ?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `contract` (starting with lower-case `c`). At least that's the case in web3.py, and would assume that it is also the case in web3.js.

Answer (score 11):

```
TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
```

This is a generic javascript error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor

You call a 'new' on an object ('web3.eth.Contract') without a constructor.

It looks like your jumping from web3 versions.

In web3 < 1.0, this is the syntax (lowercase c, no 'new'):

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
var version = web3.version.api; // "0.2.0"
```

In web3 1.0 (not ready for production yet) this is the syntax (uppercase C, 'new'):

```
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
var version = web3.version; // "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Note that the `contract` keyword in web3<1.0 has the lower case `c` letter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the web3 < 1.0 which support [this syntax](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract):

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
```

Your code example with the `new` is for web3@^1.0

Comment: In fact, as user goodvibration commented, I must use the lower case of "contract" like this : "web3.eth.contract".

Answer (score 0):

use

```
const {Web3} = require("web3")
```

instead of

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
```