# Why does webjs 1.0.0 cdn show api 0.20.7?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I have a project where rather than installing modules I have to import web3.js cdn. It's possible to find it here: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/

In the project there is a specific part integrating the script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

However I am slightly confused if this is really web3.js 1.0.0.

According to this [source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/typeerror-web3-eth-contract-is-not-a-constructor-what-is-the-reason), if the web3 is under 1.0 you initiate contracts as

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
```

In web3 1.0 and above instead:

```
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
```

I am forced in my syntax to use the one provided for versions below 1.0, yet I am importing web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34.

I decided to print the web3 version using

```
console.log(web3.version);
```

and in my console it appears to be 0.20.7.

Keep in mind that I tried other packages (from those that work as most don't lol) and the result is similar (I may get another version such as 0.20.8)

----------------Solution in short:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/yourInfuraKey"));
    }
})

</script>
```

Comment: From the source it appears to be 1.0.0-beta34. How do you instantiate `web3` variable? Perhaps some other dependency is bringing an old version.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem. The 0.20.7 version is somehow from metamask. When I go with another browser or incognito on the same page I'm getting web3 not defined, despite using <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have loaded web3.min.js it should have created `Web3` (with uppercase). Then you have to instantiate your own instance:

```
web3 = new Web3("http://ropsten.infura.io/v3/MyOtterToken")
```

Comment: Oops 
I literally forgot this step despite using it multiple times before. Thanks